# CGAL: .locate(): 'initializing': cannot convert from '_Ty2' to 'CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator<T,Alloc>'

Tags: c++, cgal

I am planning on determining the shortest path on a mesh. For that I want to use one of the convenience functionalities to calculate the closest point on the input surface mesh(https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_shortest_path/index.html#Surface_mesh_shortest_pathClassMore).

For that I want to use this function: Face_location CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path< Traits, VIM, HIM, FIM, VPM >::locate(const Point_3 &  p, const AABB_tree< AABBTraits > &  tree )  const
(https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_shortest_path/classCGAL_1_1Surface__mesh__shortest__path.html#a89cf147a8f486c1dd6382b36ea268cbc)

I believe below are the important lines of my code:

```
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_default_triangulation_3.h>
#include <CGAL/make_surface_mesh.h>
#include <CGAL/Implicit_surface_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/distance.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_halfedge_graph_segment_primitive.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_shortest_path/Surface_mesh_shortest_path.h>
#include <CGAL/Surface_mesh_shortest_path.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_items_with_id_3.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;
typedef Kernel::Vector_3 Vector;
typedef std::pair<Point, Vector> Point_with_normal;
typedef std::vector<Point_with_normal> PointList;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel, CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3> Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::AABB_halfedge_graph_segment_primitive<Polyhedron> Primitive;
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<Kernel, Primitive> Traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<Traits> Tree;

typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path_traits<Kernel, Polyhedron> Traits2;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path<Traits2> Surface_mesh_shortest_path;
typedef CGAL::Surface_mesh_shortest_path<Traits2>::Face_location Face_location;

    Polyhedron output_mesh;
    PointList points2;
#load a mesh into output_mesh and a point cloud with normals into points2

    Tree tree(CGAL::edges(output_mesh).first,
        CGAL::edges(output_mesh).second,
        output_mesh);
    tree.accelerate_distance_queries();
    Surface_mesh_shortest_path shortest_paths(output_mesh);
    Point pt = points2[0].first;
    Face_location fl = shortest_paths.locate(pt,tree);
```

If I don't have the last line included the code builds fine, but when the last line is included I get the following error:

Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from '_Ty2' to 'CGAL::internal::In_place_list_iterator'

This error refers to line 2895 in Surface_mesh_shortest_path.h:

```
  template <class AABBTraits>
  static Face_location locate(const Point_3& location,
                              const AABB_tree<AABBTraits>& tree,
                              const Triangle_mesh& tm,
                              Vertex_point_map vertexPointMap,
                              const Traits& traits = Traits())
  {
    typename Traits::Construct_barycentric_coordinates_in_triangle_3 cbcit3(traits.construct_barycentric_coordinates_in_triangle_3_object());
    typename AABB_tree<AABBTraits>::Point_and_primitive_id result = tree.closest_point_and_primitive(location);

    face_descriptor f = result.second;
    Barycentric_coordinates b = cbcit3(triangle_from_face(f, tm, vertexPointMap), result.first);
    return Face_location(f, b);
  }
```

Line 2895 is: face_descriptor f = result.second;

I don't really understand what the problem is. From a google search '_Ty2' may refer to a pointer. It seems that the variable types that I give to the function locate may be wrong, but I believe I am giving it what it wants.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your example is incomplete (what's the definition of Traits?). Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yeah that's right I forgot some type definitions. I have now edited my question and added them.

Comment: Sorry if this is a ignorant question, but is there a specific reason for why you need the AABB tree to use `AABB_halfedge_graph_segment_primitive` instead of `AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive`?

Comment: I just recently started using cgal and I started out with this tutorial: https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html#aabb_tree_examples_5 
In it they are using AABB_halfedge_graph_segment_primitive and just changing AABB_halfedge_graph_segment_primitive to AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive creates an error for me.
Do you think that may be the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I was doing some experiments with your example based on the code here: https://gist.github.com/dmontagu/ea9f7e60e83fc8693245d9e1ddcc31aa#file-mesh-cpp-L212 When I change your code to use `AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive` instead of `AABB_halfedge_graph_segment_primitive` and replace `CGAL::edges` with `CGAL::faces` in `main`, your example compiles for me. But I don't know enough about CGAL to tell if this will give you the result you need.

Comment: So chaning `AABB_halfedge_graph_segment_primitive` to `AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive` and replacing `CGAL::edges` with `CGAL::faces` build without the last line, but if the last line is included I still get the same '_Ty2' error.
Howeve using the tutorial you mentioned I was able solve that issue as well. I ended up using the following, which worked:
`std::unique_ptr<Surface_mesh_shortest_path> smsp_{ nullptr };
    std::unique_ptr<AABB_tree> aabb_{ nullptr };
    smsp_ = std::make_unique<Surface_mesh_shortest_path>(output_mesh);
    aabb_ = std::make_unique<AABB_tree>();`    Thanks!